# Flash Audio Player that I can dynamically change source

Tags: flash, html5-audio

Currently I have a single audio element with multiple dynamically loaded html controls (play, pause, seek) around the site but I need a Flash alternative for browsers that don't support the audio tag.

So I would like to either be able to dynamically insert it where the normal html controls would be or manipulate it the same way via those html controls.

Comment: This seems to be possible with an API like [MediaElementJS](http://mediaelementjs.com/). 

Consider well whether it's worth it though. It's 2016. The use of Flash is rapidly declining and the audio tag is supported by [every major browser.](http://caniuse.com/#feat=audio)

Comment: Their API refers to the html5 elements only but I'll try it out. Yeah I know it's declining rapidly and I'd rather get people to update from their IE 6  - 8 than use it.

Comment: Yeah. Re Flash, check out the "API" section on the front page: `MediaElementPlayer is a complete audio and video player, but you can also use just the MediaElement object which replaces <video> and <audio> with a Flash player that mimics the properties, methods, and events of HTML MediaElement API.`